# Add Numbers to United States Map Help R, R-Studio?

Tags: r

Can someone help me with creating a map in `R`?  I need to make a map of the number of retail stores a company has in each state.  All I need is the store count displayed in each state.

For example: if there are 150 stores in California and 250 in Texas, I need the map to display 150 within the California borders and 250 within the Texas borders.

I created a map with:

```
m = map("states", region = c('Alabama', etc....))
```

I tried adding the numbers as a label but that didn't work.

```
m = map("states", region = c('Alabama', etc....), labels = c('24','56',etc....))
```

I must be missing something. I have a .csv file with the state name and the number of stores in each state.  Is there an easy way to translate this into a graph? I'd like to avoid doing it by hand in Excel.

---

Thanks! That worked. Does anyone know how to deal with the labels that do not fit within a states boarders? Also, does anyone know how to color code states based on the number value? The image of the map and code I am using is below:
[image: US Map With Counts]
`library("maps")`

`map.text("state", regions=c("alabama",
                            "arizona",
                            "arkansas",
                            "california",
                            "colorado",
                            "connecticut",
                            "delaware",
                            "district of columbia",
                            "florida",
                            "georgia",
                            "idaho",
                            "illinois",
                            "indiana",
                            "iowa",
                            "kansas",
                            "kentucky",
                            "louisiana",
                            "maine",
                            "maryland",
                            "massachusetts:main",
                            "michigan:north",
                            "minnesota",
                            "mississippi",
                            "missouri",
                            "montana",
                            "nebraska",
                            "nevada",
                            "new hampshire",
                            "new jersey",
                            "new mexico",
                            "new york:main",
                            "north carolina:main",
                            "north dakota",
                            "ohio",
                            "oklahoma",
                            "oregon",
                            "pennsylvania",
                            "rhode island",
                            "south carolina",
                            "south dakota",
                            "tennessee",
                            "texas",
                            "utah",
                            "vermont",
                            "virginia:main",
                            "washington:main",
                            "west virginia",
                            "wisconsin",
                            "wyoming"), labels=as.character(c(29,
                                                              38,
                                                              13,
                                                              173,
                                                              21,
                                                              12,
                                                              5,
                                                              1,
                                                              108,
                                                              59,
                                                              7,
                                                              40,
                                                              46,
                                                              3,
                                                              9,
                                                              40,
                                                              23,
                                                              8,
                                                              24,
                                                              20,
                                                              49,
                                                              9,
                                                              14,
                                                              27,
                                                              2,
                                                              4,
                                                              12,
                                                              7,
                                                              21,
                                                              12,
                                                              60,
                                                              73,
                                                              2,
                                                              108,
                                                              18,
                                                              14,
                                                              71,
                                                              1,
                                                              35,
                                                              1,
                                                              49,
                                                              117,
                                                              10,
                                                              4,
                                                              39,
                                                              27,
                                                              18,
                                                              10,
                                                              2)))`

Comment: You should add which R package you were using

Comment: library("maps")

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
library("maps")
map.text("state", regions=c("california", "texas"), labels=as.character(c(125, 250)))
```

[image: R plot]

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent [blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/maps-in-r-choropleth-maps/) that goes step by step into creating a choropleth map.  Their example is specific to Europe, although you should have no trouble incorporating your own data.  I particularly like how they incorporate the powerful graphics engine of ggplot2 in their workflow.

[image]

```
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

# read administrative boundaries (change folder appropriately)
eurMap <- readShapePoly(fn="NUTS_2010_60M_SH/Shape/data/NUTS_RG_60M_2010")

# read downloaded data (change folder appropriately)
eurEdu <- read.csv("educ_thexp_1_Data.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
eurEdu$Value <- as.double(eurEdu$Value) #format as numeric

# merge map and data
eurEduMapDf <- merge(eurMapDf, eurEdu, by.x="id", by.y="GEO")
eurEduMapDf <- eurEduMapDf[order(eurEduMapDf$order),]

#limit data to main Europe
europe.limits <- geocode(c("Cape Fligely, Rudolf Island, Franz Josef Land, Russia", "Gavdos, Greece", "Faja Grande, Azores", "Severny Island, Novaya Zemlya, Russia"))

eurEduMapDf <- subset(eurEduMapDf, long > min(europe.limits$lon) & long < max(europe.limits$lon) & lat > min(europe.limits$lat) & lat < max(europe.limits$lat))

# ggplot mapping
# data layer
m0 <- ggplot(data=eurEduMapDf)
# empty map (only borders)
m1 <- m0 + geom_path(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color='gray') + coord_equal()

# fill with education expenditure data
m2 <- m1 + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=Value))

# inverse order (to have visible borders)
m0 <- ggplot(data=eurEduMapDf)
m1 <- m0 + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=Value)) + coord_equal()
m2 <- m1 + geom_path(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color='black')
m2

# over a GoogleMap (not working if not correctly projected)
map <- get_map(location = 'Europe', zoom=4)
m0 <- ggmap(map)
m1 <- m0 + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=Value), data=eurEduMapDf, alpha=.9)
m2 <- m1 + geom_path(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), data=eurEduMapDf, color='black')

# add text
library(doBy)
txtVal <- summaryBy(long + lat + Value ~ id, data=eurEduMapDf, FUN=mean, keep.names=T)
m3 <- m2 + geom_text(aes(x=long, y=lat, label=Value), data=txtVal, col="yellow", cex=3)
```